# Is there a way to access the (lexically) current colour inside Graphics?

Tags: graphics, color

Note that this is not a duplicate of [the question over there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/way-to-find-color-at-a-point-in-a-graphics). That one asks for a given point, while I'm asking about the lexical structure (which, of course, is not directly related to any point in the final graphics).

What I want to know is whether there's a way to access the currently set colour. For example, let's assume I write the following function:

```
mydisk[p_,r_]:={EdgeForm[Darker[CurrentColor]],Disk[p,r]}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Graphics[{Red, mydisk[{0,0},1], Green, mydisk[{1,1},1]}]
```

it should be equivalent to

```
Graphics[{Red, {EdgeForm[Darker[Red]], Disk[{0,0},1]},
          Green, {EdgeForm[Darker[Green]], Disk[{1,1},1]}}]
```

Is this possible, and if so, what would I write in the place of `CurrentColor`?

Comment: +1, good question!  I wanted to ask this myself at some point.  This will come up when trying to convert a Mathematica `Graphics`-expression to some other format (e.g. export to some special format).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[`CurrentValue["Color"]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CurrentValue.html) seems to be doing the trick (not documented).

```
mydisk[p_, r_] := {Dynamic[EdgeForm[Darker[CurrentValue["Color"]]]], 
  Disk[p, r]}
```

`Dynamic` is needed because the value has to be evaluated by FrontEnd at the time of rendering. Here is the result:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[10]], Red, mydisk[{0, 0}, 1], 
  Green, mydisk[{1, 1}, 1]}]
```

[image]

`CurrentValue` is like a box of chocolate. It has a lot of features (mostly FE callbacks), many undocumented, but usually a very present surprise when it works.

A few other items that work with `CurrentValue`: `"Thickness"`, `"Opacity"`, `"Dashing"`, `"FontFamily"`, `"FontSize"`, `"FontSlant"`, `"FontWeight"`, `"FontColor"` and `"FontOpacity"`.

Comment: A real treat, that!

Comment: Great solution. Some experiments show that other values which can be accessed with `CurrentValue` are `"Thickness"`, `"Opacity"`, `"Dashing"`, `"FontFamily"`, `"FontSize"`, `"FontSlant"`, `"FontWeight"`, `"FontColor"` and `"FontOpacity"`.

Comment: I updated the post with @celtschk's findings.  This information is too valuable to keep it in a volatile comment that may disappear any day.

Comment: For many more see [Items known by CurrentValue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1379/121)