# Why doesn't PlotMarker option None return no PlotMarkers?

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

After reading the `PlotMarkers` documentation it seems to be all or nothing. For example if you wanted markers on some of you lines the code below seems possible/probable given the documentation:

```
ListPlot[Table[n^(1/p), {p, 4}, {n, 10}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledSquare]", 10.9`}, None, 
   None, {"\[EmptyCircle]", 9}}]
```

But this doesn't work.

[image]

It seems that an empty string is the only way to get no markers for some of the lines if you choose markers on others. Is this correct or am I misusing `PlotMarkers`?

When using an empty circle marker the background is transparent so the line can be seen underneath. If I want filled white circle with an `EdgeForm` colour that obscures the plot line I can make one and use it as a marker as per instructions in the documentation but then I run into the headache of wanting to parse the default (or other) colours to the `EdgeForm` directive. This can be developed but what a headache. Has anyone got any easy work arounds?

```
ListPlot[Table[n^(1/p), {p, 4}, {n, 10}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[ColoursGoHere,Thick, Thick]], White, 
      Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], 0.05}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sticking with `\[EmptyCircle]`, maybe  `Style[\[EmptyCircle]
 , Background -> White] ` ?

Comment: @TomD the background is not confined to the inside of the circle. For a small font size and no other lines nearby this is not really a problem. However it is possible that the backgrounded "square" could overlap other lines. This is best seen in this example with background red and a larger font.

Comment: You are right, of course.  That is good to know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer to your first question is that `PlotMarkers` doesn't really use a graphics primitive, but uses font based markers as a proxy for it. This can lead to [errors in positioning](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/5) on some OSes.

I'm guessing that `PlotStyle` has something of the form `ToString@HoldForm[...]` when the input is a list, which is why `None` and `False` or anything else get converted to strings. This might well be a bug/undesired behaviour, because `AxesLabel -> None` and `AxesLabel -> {"x", None}` don't behave the same way. It does seem to work for `Null` though, although I wouldn't have guessed it at first.

For the second question, you can adapt [Yu-Sung's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5143/5) and use `CurrentValue["Color"]` to colour your markers. Here's your example modified to do this:

```
ListPlot[Table[n^(1/p), {p, 4}, {n, 10}], Joined -> True, PlotMarkers :> 
    {{Graphics[{Dynamic@EdgeForm[{CurrentValue["Color"], Thick}], 
        FaceForm[White], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], 0.05}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: `CurrentValue["Color"]` is indeed a good, and concise, solution to this. Anyone know why it isn't documented?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch CurrentValue is poorly documented indeed. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/items-known-by-currentvalue

Answer (score 16):

The `None` option is the default, and is only for use when applied to all datasets as one:

```
ListPlot[Table[n^(1/p), {p, 4}, {n, 10}],
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> None]
```

You can use `""`, `Null` or `Spacer[0]` for the result you require.

Comment: Just for completeness: you could also use `Graphics[{}]` in place of `""`.

Comment: In other words, the workaround is to use anything that formats as "empty" or invisible.

Comment: I was using `""` but wanted to clarify that `None` was inappropriate. thanks

Comment: `Null` now prints "Null" instead of showing nothing (version 13.0)

Answer (score 2):

Addressing only the second part of the question it may be solved using:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[n^(1/p), {p, 4}, {n, 10}],
  PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{{White, Disk[]}, {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.05}
]
```

[image]

When the first argument of `Graphics` is a list the style directives are prefixed.

Related:

- [How to make PlotMarkers constructed from Graphics track plot style?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56327/121)
- [Change the inner color of markers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56155/121)