# Are plotting markers with inscribed letters possible?

Tags: plotting

I have large data consisting of values obtained by sweeping across three parameters (e, w, and f). I want to plot all this data on one graph using different shapes for e (e.g., circle, triangle, square, and diamond), different colors for w, and a letter inside the shape for f. So far I have

```
Jw1e1 = {{16, 832}, {32, 3150}, {64, 12237}, {128, 48212}};
J1 = ListLogPlot[Jw1e1, PlotMarkers -> (Style[Framed[H], Red]), 
  Frame -> True]
Jw1e3 = {{16, 826}, {32, 3127}, {64, 12145}, {128, 47851}};
J3 = ListLogPlot[Jw1e1, PlotMarkers -> (Style[Framed[H], Blue]), 
  Frame -> True]
Show[J1, J3]
```

I cannot figure out how have a square, circle, etc. appear as the specified shape by changing `Framed[H]`. If I replace `Framed[H]` by `Circle[]`, Circle[{0, 0}] appears on my plots and replacing by `Circle[H]`, `Circle[H]` appears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** Using some of the ideas in the linked Q/As, you can get a finer customization of your markers:

```
Jw1e1 = {{16, 832}, {32, 3150}, {64, 12237}, {128, 48212}};
Jw1e3 = {{16, 826}, {32, 3127}, {64, 12145}, {128, 47851}};
(* second list modified so that the two plots do not overlap*)
lists = {Jw1e1, {1, .1} # & /@ Jw1e3} ;
markerDisk = Graphics[{Opacity[.6],
 Dynamic@EdgeForm[{clr = CurrentValue["Color"], Thick}],
 Dynamic[FaceForm[{Opacity[1], Lighter[clr, .3]}]], Disk[], Opacity[1],
 Style[Text[#], White, Bold, 16]}, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.01]] &;

ListLogPlot[lists, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 500,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 35,
 PlotMarkers :> ({markerDisk[#], 0.15} & /@ {A, B})]]
```

[image]

---

From [Docs > PlotMarkers > Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotMarkers.html):

[image]

```
mrkr = Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[], Style[Text[H], Red, Bold, 24]}]; 
ListLogPlot[Jw1e1, PlotMarkers -> {mrkr, .2}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Related Q/As**

[Why doesn' t PlotMarker option None return no PlotMarkers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5400/125)

[ListPlot with plotmarkers determined by point](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7408/125)

Comment: Quick question. Why does the command 
`markerDisk2 = 
  Graphics[{Opacity[.5], 
     Dynamic@EdgeForm[{clr = CurrentValue["Color"], Thick}], 
     Dynamic[FaceForm@Lighter@clr], Rectangle[], Opacity[1], 
     Style[Text[A], Black, Bold, 18]}, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.2]] &;
ListLogPlot[Je1w1H, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 35, 
 PlotMarkers :> ({markerDisk2[#], 0.15} & /@ {A, B})] `
have the letters offset from the Rectangle?

Answer (score 6):

You were nearly there:

```
Jw1e1 = {{16, 832}, {32, 3150}, {64, 12237}, {128, 48212}};

J1 = ListLogPlot[Jw1e1, 

  PlotMarkers -> (Style[Framed[H, RoundingRadius -> 20], Red]), 

  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The nice thing here is that you can play around with `RoundingRadius` and that longer/larger text markers will be properly framed as well.

```
J1 = ListLogPlot[Jw1e1, 

  PlotMarkers -> (Style[

     Framed["Longer than strictly necessary", RoundingRadius -> 20], 

     Red]), Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Driving it home:

```
J1 = ListLogPlot[Jw1e1, 

  PlotMarkers -> 

   Framed[Style["Larger than \n strictly necessary", Large, Red], 

    RoundingRadius -> 20], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Interesting these `RoundingRadius` property. 1+

Comment: Unfortunately with this method plot markers will be positioned [imprecisely](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/280), so the [approach suggested by @kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18825/280) is preferred.