# Creating plot markers with centered text

Tags: plotting, graphics, alignment

I want to create a series of plot markers which are circles, squares etc. with 2-3 letter codes centered within the marker. My current attempt looks like this:

```
{
t4dot =  Graphics[{Green, Disk[{0, 0}, ImageScaled[0.07]], 
          Style[Text["T4"], Yellow, Bold, 18]}],
gk1dot = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}], 
          Style[Text["Gk1", {0.5, 0.5}], Yellow, Bold, 14]}]
}
```

which makes:

[image]

The "T4" marker is about right (although the centering is an issue). Obviously, I haven't been able to get `rectangle[]` to scale properly. When I tried to use these graphics as plot markers the circle and rectangle were huge and swamped the graph whilst the text stayed the same size.

I am aiming to make markers for which the graphics primitive and the text are nicely centered and scale as a group. I want to be able to call the resulting graphics with something like:

```
ListPlot[{{5, 7}, {4, 6}}, PlotMarkers -> {{t4dot, 16}, {gk1dot, 18}},
  PlotRange -> {{3, 6}, {3, 8}}, ImagePadding -> 35]
```

Any ideas about how to achieve this?

Also, I have looked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7408/listplot-with-plotmarkers-determined-by-point) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18823/are-plotting-markers-with-inscribed-letters-possible) and I noticed that Mathematica often offsets the text towards the top-left corner of the graphic. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Have a look here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18828/131. Might be considered borderline duplicate (as already linked by yourself).

Comment: @YvesKlett, Yes, it is borderline. I think I can make the solution in that post work for me (but it's not ideal). The main downfall is that it still doesn't center the text nicely and cannot be applied to specific plotmarker shapes. For example, if I have a long piece of text I cannot see a way of using `Framed[]` to make a square around it (it would be nice to be able make diamonds as well!).

Comment: Understood - just wanted to point you there in case this helped right away. As for the centering, I feel `Framed` does not do too bad, but perhaps you can come up with a really bad example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to center the `Rectangle` at `{.5, .5}`, and you also have to have two datasets. Simply feeding `{{5, 7}, {4, 6}}` is interpreted by `ListPlot` as a single dataset. For clarity, I've added some extra points.

```
t4dot = Graphics[{Green, Disk[{0, 0}, (ImageScaled@.07)], 
     Style[Text["T4", Offset@{2, -1}], Yellow, Bold, 18]}];
gk1dot = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[ImageScaled[{.5,.5}-.07], ImageScaled[{.5,.5}+.07]], 
     Style[Text["Gk1", Offset@{2, -1}], Yellow, Bold, 14]}];

ListPlot[{{{4, 6}, {5, 7}}, {{4, 3}, {5, 2}}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{t4dot, 1}, {gk1dot, 1}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{3, 6}, {1, 8}}, ImagePadding -> 35]
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution looks good, unfortunately, your definition for `gk1dot` throws up errors for me. I'm running 8.0.4 on a Mac-SL

Comment: @geordie It was just missing a bracket due to editing. Corrected now.

Comment: Many thanks. The centering is still slightly variable. Is there a way to 'force' mathematica to get it dead center (or am i opening a graphical can of worms)?

Comment: @geordie I think you always have to manually finetune these kind of things, but I may be wrong. The links you have included show some other solutions, e.g. with `Inset`. Might be rewarding to experiment with it.