# Change the inner color of markers

Tags: plotting, color, marker

I would like to have a marker with white as its inner color, to be able to make this kind of graph:

[image]

If I use `PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledSquare]", White]`, it changes both the inner color + border color but not the inner color only.

If I use `PlotMarkers -> Style["\[EmptySquare]", White]`, the line of the curve goes above the marker.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: `PlotMarkers->Graphics[...]` as in [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18823/are-plotting-markers-with-inscribed-letters-possible?rq=1)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Version 10 you can use the `PlotTheme` `"OpenMarkersThick"`:

```
data = Table[{x, x^k}, {k, 1, 4}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}]

ListLinePlot[data, PlotTheme -> {"OpenMarkersThick", "LargeLabels"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {x, x^2, x^3, x^4}]
```

[image]

Comment: PlotTheme looks powerful. Will try it as soon as Mathematica 10 is downloaded!

Answer (score 23):

`\[FilledSquare]` is a font glyph and you cannot color parts of it.

I believe you need to draw your markers with `Graphics` primitives.  For example:

```
square[in_, out_: Black, size_: 12] :=
 Graphics[{in, EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[2], out}], Rectangle[]},
   PlotRangePadding -> 0,
   ImageSize -> size]

data = {{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}};

ListLinePlot[data, 
 PlotMarkers -> square /@ {Red, Green, Blue}
]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[data,
  PlotMarkers -> square @@@ {{Yellow, Red}, {White, Blue}, {Black, Pink}}
]
```

[image]

---

**Update: proof that this method can easily be used for markers of arbitrary shape.**

Generic `marker` function:

```
marker[prim_, opts___][in_: White, out_: Black, size_: 13] :=
 Graphics[{in, EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[2], Opacity[1], out}], prim},
  opts, ImageSize -> size]
```

Shapes:

```
square  = marker @ Rectangle[];
circle  = marker @ Disk[];
diamond = marker @ Polygon[{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}}];
triangle =
 marker[
   Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}], 
   AlignmentPoint -> {0, 1/Sqrt[3]}
 ];
```

Plot:

```
SeedRandom[12]

ListLinePlot[
  Accumulate /@ RandomReal[3, {4, 10}] {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
  PlotMarkers ->
    {square[], circle[Yellow], diamond[Brown, Pink], triangle[Magenta, Purple]},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

Comment: @Öskå Go ahead and edit.  I'll probably refactor to make it more terse, as is my style, but I'm out of time now.  See you later. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard First time that I could downvote one of your answers :)

Comment: @eldo What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I understood the question like @chuy and myself (with a V9 answer): Fill DIFFERENT `PlotMarkers` shapes with a white background. Your answer only produces rectangles. Please excuse if I misunderstood something.

Comment: @eldo You could use Primitives to produce any shape you like.  Unlike other answers this one addresses the question in the Title: *change the inner color of markers*, not merely making centers white.  (I wasn't aware of the theme `"OpenMarkersThick"` when I wrote this answer or surely would have included it.)  I expect that chuy will earn the Accept but I don't think this is a bad answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Resolved

Comment: @eldo Please see update.

Comment: Rotating the `Rectangle` is smart :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A merited upvote after an unmerited downvote. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Your implementation of the triangle plot markers is incorrect as well as @eldo's: the center of the triangle is located on 1/3 of its height, not 1/2 as in your implementation. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54537/280).

Comment: @Alexey I missed that Q&A despite its popularity. +2

Comment: Note that plot markers are aligned according to the `AlignmentPoint` option of `Graphics`. So if you add into your current triangle specification `AlignmentPoint -> {0, 1/Sqrt[3]}` you will get correct placement of the triangles. This value can be found via `RegionCentroid@Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]`. Of course for the other shapes in your answer this option should be different.

Comment: +1. Did not know that the `AlignmentPoint` can also be specified on the first level inside of the first argument of `Graphics` and in this case it overrides this option specified in the rest of arguments of `Graphics`. However it is undocumented and may be changed in future.

Comment: @Alexey That is not what my code is doing.  (Or at least not what I intend.)  I changed the definition to `marker[prim_, opts___]` to pass options to `Graphics`.  Sorry to disappoint. :-/

Comment: Note that in more recent versions, you might need to add `ImagePadding -> 1`.  See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272775/custom-plotmarkers-with-graphics-get-cut).

Comment: How can I increase the size of Disk or Rectangle in the marker?

Answer (score 5):

You could build your own `PlotMarkers`

```
ngon[p_, q_] := 
 Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 Pi k q/p], Sin[2 Pi k q/p]}, {k, p}]]

g1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}];
g2 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, Rectangle[{1, 1}]}];
g3 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, ngon[4, 1]}];
g4 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]}];

ListLinePlot[Table[n^(1/p), {p, 4}, {n, 10}],
Filling -> Axis,
PlotLegends -> Automatic,
PlotMarkers -> Table[{s, 0.05}, {s, {g1, g2, g3, g4}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the triangle plot markers are placed incorrectly in this answer: the center of the triangle is located on 1/3 of its height, not 1/2. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54537/280).

Answer (score 3):

### ChartElementData["EmptyMarkers"]

```
ListLinePlot[4 Range[6] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 20}], 
  Filling -> Thread[Range[5] -> List /@ Range[2, 6]],
  PlotMarkers -> Thread[{ChartElementData["EmptyMarkers"][[All, 1]], .05}], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

To get thicker edges, use

```
PlotMarkers -> Thread[{ChartElementData["EmptyMarkers"][[All, 1]] /. 
    Thickness[_] :> AbsoluteThickness[3], .05}]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the triangle markers with this approach will be positioned incorrectly: try `ListLinePlot[Table[{i,j},{i,6},{j,6}],PlotMarkers->Thread[{ChartElementData["EmptyMarkers"][[All,1]],.1}],GridLines->{None,All}]/.p_Polygon:>{Blue,PointSize[.15],Point[RegionCentroid[p]]}` to see this. Detailed explanations are [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54537/280).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, you are right.  It is easier to see that the triangle marker is not centered at `{.5, .5}` is  to evaluate `ChartElementData["EmptyMarkers"][[4, 1]] /. 
  Opacity[0] -> Opacity[.5] // 
 Show[#, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {{.5}, {.5}}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Red, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}] &`

Comment: Actually as I explain [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54537/280) the triangle should NOT be centered at `{.5, .5}`, but at `RegionCentro‌​id` at `{.5, 1/3}` (for the upper triangle).

Comment: @Alexey, yes,;actually I meant to say it **is** centered at `{.5,.5}` .