# Why does Rotate in PlotMarkers behave strangely?

Tags: plotting, bugs, legending, rotation

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 12.0**

---

While answering [Change the inner color of markers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56155/121) I came across a behavior that may be a bug.
I would like to know if there is another explanation.

First a basic example of normal behavior:

```
ListLinePlot[{Prime~Array~12, Fibonacci~Array~12},
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Brown, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 13],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

Note that the markers are included in the legend.  But now if I [`Rotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rotate.html) the [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rectangle.html):

```
ListLinePlot[{Prime~Array~12, Fibonacci~Array~12},
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Brown, Rectangle[] ~Rotate~ (Pi/4)}, ImageSize -> 13],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

The markers disappear from the legend.  They do appear if I `Rotate` the entire `Graphics`, however the markers are not scaled as before and they clip:

```
ListLinePlot[{Prime~Array~12, Fibonacci~Array~12},
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Brown, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 13] ~Rotate~ (Pi/4),
 PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

1. Is use of `Rotate` in plot markers simply unsupported or is this a bug?
2. Is there a way to use rotated primitives for markers and not break the legend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One workaround is to use `GeometricTransformation` instead of `Rotate`. By specifying coordinates in the `Offset` form we can achieve consistent size of markers on the plot and in the legend. The cropping of the markers in the legend can be avoided by increasing their sizes as [MinHsuan Peng suggests](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56324/280):

```
ListLinePlot[{Prime~Array~12, Fibonacci~Array~12}, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  Graphics[{Brown, 
    GeometricTransformation[
     Rectangle[Offset[{-5, -5}], Offset[{5, 5}]], 
     RotationTransform[Pi/4]]}], 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 15}]]
```

> [image: plot]

Comparison of the `InputForm`s of the plot generated with `Rotate` and with `GeometricTransformation` reveals that another workaround is to specify explicitly the rotation point:

```
ListLinePlot[{Prime~Array~12, Fibonacci~Array~12}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Brown, Rotate[Rectangle[], (Pi/4), {0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 13], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

> [image: plot]

This workaround proves that `Rotate` in `PlotMarkers` is supported but has a bug when used without explicit rotation point as the third argument. It is interesting that specifying `Rectangle` coordinates in the `Offset` form reveals even more strange bugs:

```
ListLinePlot[{Prime~Array~12, Fibonacci~Array~12}, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  Graphics[{Brown, 
    Rectangle[Offset[{-5, -5}], Offset[{5, 5}]]~Rotate~(Pi/4)}, 
   ImageSize -> 10], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

> [image: plot2]

But with explicit rotation point it is OK:

```
ListLinePlot[{Prime~Array~12, Fibonacci~Array~12}, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  Graphics[{Brown, Rotate[Rectangle[Offset[{-5, -5}], Offset[{5, 5}]], (Pi/4), {0, 0}]}, 
   ImageSize -> 13], PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 15}]]
```

> [image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

A workaround to question 2 is to increase legend marker size:

`LineLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 20}]`