# Plot points shifted (a lot) in output and PNG export but not in PDF export

Tags: graphics, bugs, geometric-transform, rendering, scidraw

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 12.0.0**

---

Consider the following code:

```
Needs["SciDraw`"]
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]
plotData = {{1, 0}};
markers[size_] := Graphics[{PolygonMarker["Disk", Offset[size]]}];
plotA = ListPlot[plotData, PlotMarkers -> markers[8]];
plot = Figure[FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plotA]}], CanvasSize -> {3, 2}]
```

[image]

The plotted point is not where it's supposed to be, that is, at `{1,0}`. In fact, it is shifted by precisely `{-0.5,0.5}`. Only when exported to pdf (last panel) does the point appear at the right position.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Note that both `SciDraw` and `PolygonPlotMarkers` seem to influence the result. At least I can't reproduce the phenomenon when not using both of those packages. However, independent of what those packages do, what could possibly lead to a different output in these two file formats?

If it matters, I have tested this using version 11.0.1 and version 10.4.1 on 64 bit Linux.

`SciDraw` is available from [here](http://scidraw.nd.edu/).

`PolygonPlotMarkers` is available from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10/85094#85094).

Comment: Note that with `PlotMarkers -> None` you get huge `Point`s in the final plot. So at least your  piece of code with `Figure` somehow introduces a problem with scale. Please distill your code upto a **minimal working example** for reproducing the problem. Your current example is overcomplicated.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov True, it's not a trivial example, but unfortunately I every single line seems to matter to reproduce the effect. I really don't know how to make it more simple.

Comment: Besides an actual answer I would also appreciate any comments on how to improve the question or how to isolate the problem.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138926/280

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That is interesting. Do your PolygonPlotMarkers scale in the same way as ArrowHeads? Also, it seems to me that the ArrowHeads problem is only related to the size of the features, which would explain why I have to use such a small size for the plot markers. But I don't yet see how it relates to *position*. Do you?

Comment: With Offset size specifications my markers have fixed sizes (you can check the implementation). But (as noticed in the linked answer) applying  ScalingTransform converts Offset coordinates into ordinary coordinates what may cause all the strange distortions you notice.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That makes sense. Do you think there is a way around this? I tried `Scaled[size]` instead of `Offset[size]`, which has the same effect. Just providing a number doesn't scale the markers at all, not even in `plotA`, i.e., without `SciDraw`. Is there another way to scale these markers to the desired size?

Comment: I'm not completely sure but this bug may be related too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56329/280 (we need to check what point and in what way is specified as fixed in the ScalingTransform).

Comment: On how to improve the quality of the question: reduce the number of markers used and the number of datapoints to only one. If you are able to demonstrate the same problem with only one datapoint, it is the *minimal working example*.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks, that was a good suggestion. Please see the edited question. It is now evident that the shift is exactly 0.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with the `` PolygonPlotMarkers` `` package and appears with any primitive-based plot marker:

```
Needs["SciDraw`"]
plotData = {{1, 0}};
plotA = ListPlot[plotData, PlotMarkers -> Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[3]]]]
plot = Figure[FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plotA]}], CanvasSize -> {3, 2}]
```

> [image: output]
>
> [image: output]

After some digging I distilled the problem to the following:

```
g[size_] := Graphics[GeometricTransformation[{
     Inset[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[7]]}], {1, 0}],
     Inset[Style["\[FilledCircle]", Red, FontSize -> 15], {1, 0}]},
    {{216, 0}, {0, 144}}],
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 216}, {0, 144}}, ImageSize -> size];

g /@ {150, 200, 300, 400}
```

> [image: screenshot]

Here is how it looks `Export`ed to PDF:

```
Export["i.pdf", %] // SystemOpen
```

> [image: screenshot]

In the above we have the same affine transformation applied to two `Inset`s: the first contains `Graphics`, the second contains a glyph. Both `Inset`s have identical second arguments which specify where they will be placed in the enclosing graphics, hence one should expect that their positions will be identical as it takes place *without* applying `GeometricTransformation`:

```
Graphics[{
  Inset[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[7]]}], {1, 0}],
  Inset[Style["\[FilledCircle]", Red, FontSize -> 15], {1, 0}]},
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

> [image: graphics]

So we have faced a bug in rendering of `GeometricTransformation` by the FrontEnd. I have found two workarounds:

1. Specify explicit `AlignmentPoint` for `Graphics`:

   ```
   g[size_] := Graphics[GeometricTransformation[{
        Inset[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[6]]}, AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0}], {1, 0}],
        Inset[Style["\[FilledCircle]", Red, FontSize -> 15], {1, 0}]},
       {{216, 0}, {0, 144}}],
      Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 216}, {0, 144}}, ImageSize -> size];

   g /@ {150, 200, 300, 400}
   ```

   > [image: screenshot]
2. Specify explicit third argument for `Inset`:

   ```
   g[size_] := Graphics[GeometricTransformation[{
        Inset[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[6]]}], {1, 0}, {0, 0}],
        Inset[Style["\[FilledCircle]", Red, FontSize -> 15], {1, 0}]},
       {{216, 0}, {0, 144}}],
      Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 216}, {0, 144}}, ImageSize -> size];

   g /@ {150, 200, 300, 400}
   ```

   > [image: screenshot]

For working with the `` SciDraw` `` package the first workaround is appropriate:

```
Needs["SciDraw`"]
plotData = {{1, 0}};
plotA = ListPlot[plotData, 
   PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[5]]}, AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0}]];
plot = Figure[FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plotA]}], CanvasSize -> {3, 2}]
```

> [image: output]

I recommend reporting it to the creator of `` SciDraw` `` [Mark A. Caprio](http://physics.nd.edu/people/faculty/mark-caprio/) and to Wolfram tech support. Since the usage of primitive-based plot markers is very common, this problem should be taken quite seriously.

---

#### UPDATE

It looks like this bug is strongly related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163872/280), and the same workaround works:

```
Graphics[{GeometricTransformation[{
    Inset[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[7]]}], {100, 0}],
    Inset[Style["\[FilledCircle]", Red, FontSize -> 15], {100, 0}]},
   {{216, 0}, {0, 144}}/100]}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 216}, {0, 144}}]
```

> [image: graphics]

(I multiplied the second argument of `Inset` by `100` and divided the transformation matrix by `100`).

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for tracking down the problem. I will report the problem to both Wolfram tech support and to Caprio. I will post their reply.

Comment: The bug has been confirmed by WRI. Let's hope that they fix it.