# Why SciDraw can not handle the StreamPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, packages, scaling, scidraw

I find that the package [`SciDraw`](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) is suitable for preparing the figure in the thesis. When I use it to plot the line, it works well. For example

```
<< SciDraw`
Figure[FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[Sin[10 x],{x,0,1}]]},
  XPlotRange -> {0, 1},
  XTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, 0.2, 2],
  YPlotRange -> {0, 1},
  YTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, 0.2, 2],
  YExtendRange -> 0.04,
  FontFamily -> "Times New Roman",
  FontSize -> 14,
  XFrameLabel -> X,
  XTickTextNudge -> -5,
  YTickTextNudge -> {-5, 0},
  YFrameLabel -> Y
  ],
 CanvasUnits -> Centimeter,
 CanvasSize -> {10, 10},
 CanvasMargin -> {{1.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 0.5}}]
```

I also want to use it to produce the streamplot, but it doesn't work well: the background of the figure is in the same color, and no line can be identified. For example

```
<< SciDraw`
grad = -Grad[Sin[10 x] Cos[10 y], {x, y}];
plot = StreamPlot[grad, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Figure[FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plot]},
  XPlotRange -> {0, 1},
  XTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, 0.2, 2],
  YPlotRange -> {0, 1},
  YTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, 0.2, 2],
  YExtendRange -> 0.04,
  FontFamily -> "Times New Roman",
  FontSize -> 14,
  XFrameLabel -> X,
  XTickTextNudge -> -5,
  YTickTextNudge -> {-5, 0},
  YFrameLabel -> Y
  ],
 CanvasUnits -> Centimeter,
 CanvasSize -> {10, 10},
 CanvasMargin -> {{1.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 0.5}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: "It doesn't work well": what actually happens that is undesirable? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for your comment. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Ice0cean "A picture is worth a thousand words"

Comment: @Szabolcs Indeed it is. Also thanks for your detained interpretation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In short, this is due to a behaviour in Mathematica's graphics rendering that seems intentional, but it is very strange in this particular context: [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) coordinates are scaled by [`GeometricTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransform.html) and by [`Scale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html).   The arrowheads sizes are specified in scaled coordinates.  [Unfortunately there is no good way to specify them in absolute (offset) coordinates.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/788/12)

SciDraw adds a `GeometricTransform`, which then affects the arrowheads, and (unintentionally) upscales them to ridiculous sizes. They become so large that they fill up the viewport.

#### Workaround

To work around the problem, I suggest manually reducing the arrowhead sizes to compensate. You can do this with replacement rules.

Instead of

```
FigGraphics[plot]
```

use

```
FigGraphics[
 plot /. Arrowheads[{{s_, pos_}}] :> Arrowheads[{{0.006 s, pos}}]
]
```

---

#### The underlying problem

The below graphics display the same way regardless the value of `s`.  Also, all graphics elements scale proportionally when resizing the figure with the mouse.  This is proof that the `Arrowhead` specification is in scaled coordinates.

```
s = 5;
Graphics[
 {Arrowheads[{{0.5, 1}}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, s {1, 0}}]},
 PlotRange -> s {{0, 1}, {-.25, .25}},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now let us put in a GeometricTransform to scale everything to double size. To show the whole arrow, we manually double the plot range as well.

```
s = 5;
Graphics[
 {Arrowheads[{{0.5, 1}}], 
  GeometricTransformation[
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, s {1, 0}}], {2 {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]},
 PlotRange -> 2 s {{0, 1}, {-.25, .25}},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The scaling has affected the arrowhead.  In this particular context this makes no sense to me.  But the general behaviour is clearly intentional. The documentation of [`Scale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html) explicitly states it:

> For objects specified with scaled coordinates `Scaled[{x,y}]`, `Scale` effectively applies its transformation to the corresponding ordinary coordinates.

Thus this is perhaps not a "bug" (even though in situations like this one it is clearly undesirable).