# SciDraw increases point size

Tags: plotting, scidraw

When I make a ListPlot then hand it to Multipanel, the point size gets multiplied by some huge number. Can I control the point size from within scidraw?

Here's a basic example:

```
(*Init SciDraw*)
AppendTo[$Path, "yourpathhere/mathematica-packages"];
Quiet[<< SciDraw`]

samplePlot = 
 ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

```
DefineStyle["style", {FigurePanel -> {XPlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
    YPlotRange -> {-2, 2}}}]
Figure[Multipanel[{
   FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[samplePlot]}, {1, 1}];
   }, Dimensions -> {1, 1}]
 , Style -> "style"]
```

[image]

Comment: `samplePlot = 
 ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]` works

Comment: Interesting... yours works, but using PointSize[0.015] doesn't work, despite that it looks the same in ListPlot. I think SciDraw interprets numerical values differently, but treats words like 'Medium' the same. Possibly a bug. Unfortunately in my use case I need a very specific PointSize, so that doesn't help.

Comment: I know of one workaround, where I use super small PointSize in my original plot to compensate SciDraw's inflation. But this is (a) tedious because it requires guess and check, and (b) only helps if you saved the data you used to make the plot (or can re-make it easily). Better solutions are still welcome.

Comment: related: [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138926/why-scidraw-can-not-handle-the-streamplot)

Comment: @egwenesedai Thank you! With some editing, Szabolcs' solution works for me. I'll post an answer myself and credit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@egwenesedai linked me to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138926/why-scidraw-can-not-handle-the-streamplot) by @Szabolcs which addresses the weirdness of this behavior and gave me 90% of a solution.

For the case of plotting points, the solution is to use

```
FigGraphics[samplePlot /. PointSize[s_] :> PointSize[0.01 s]]
```

which, pasted into the code in the question, gives

[image]

In my actual use case however, I found 0.006 to be a more accurate scaling. It may depend on the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to explicitly assign the point size in the original plot command `PlotStyle -> (PointSize -> Automatic)`, for example,

```
samplePlot = 
 ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> (PointSize -> Automatic)]
```

This will render SciDraw to plot regular size of points as it is in `ListPlot`

Comment: That’s cool to know, though as a control freak I often want to specify the size. Thanks though, upvoted.