# How to get rid of the background tiny crosses when using Graphics?

Tags: graphics

I am plotting very tiny arrows. For large arrows there is no problem but for small ones, one can see little crosses in the arrow positions. I do not want to see this crosses. I just want to see no arrow if it is too small. The parameter a controls the length of the arrow. Here a very simple example:

```
a = 10^-8;
listb = {{{0, 0}, {2.1*a, -2.1*a}}, {{1, 0}, {2.1*a, 2.1*a}}};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[Norm@#2/0.0001], Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ listb]
```

How could I get rid of the tiny crosses?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a replacement at the end:

```
Graphics[{Arrowheads[Norm@#2/0.0001], Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ listb] /. 
  {_Arrowheads, Arrow[{a_, b_}] /; Norm[a - b] <= 10^-7} -> {}
```

### Update

The problem seems to be a dot at the end of the arrow under certain conditions.

```
a = 10^-8; listb = {{{0, 0}, {2.1*a, -2.1*a}}, {{1, 0}, {2.1*a, 
    2.1*a}}}; 
Graphics[{Arrowheads[Norm@#2/0.000001], Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ listb]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

enlarged:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I assume that is a consequence of the underlying graphics code used to draw it. If this is a problem, you could use an arrow head of your own, like:

```
h = Graphics[Polygon[.5 {{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}, {-.8, 0}}]];
```

and then:

```
a = 10^-8; listb = {{{0, 0}, {2.1*a, -2.1*a}}, {{1, 0}, {2.1*a, 2.1*a}}}; 

Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{Norm@#2/0.000001, Automatic, h}}], 
          Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ listb]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

enlarged:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is the problem the size of the arrowhead of the length of the line?  I take it to be the arrowhead.

Comment: It's not clear to me. I didn't see any crosses with the code posted in the question, just two dots, so I figured the OP wanted to get rid of those. (" I just want to see no arrow if it is too small.")

Comment: I figured the same.  I think the issue is that very small arrowheads still render as dots (to a point) whereas lines disappear sooner.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard♦ @Sjoerd C. de Vries By changing the size of the arrowheads: a = 10^-8;
listb = {{{0, 0}, {2.1*a, -2.1*a}}, {{1, 0}, {2.1*a, 2.1*a}}};
Graphics[{Arrowheads[Norm@#2/0.000001], Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ 
  listb] . Can you see how there is some dot/cross at the end of the arrowhead? That's the thing I want to get rid of .

Comment: I can see a small dot at the end of the arrow head. I assume that is a consequence of the underlying graphics code used to draw it. If it disturbs you, you could use an arrow head of your own, like: `h = Graphics[Polygon[.5 {{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}, {-.8, 0}}]];` and then: `a = 10^-8; listb = {{{0, 0}, {2.1*a, -2.1*a}}, {{1, 0}, {2.1*a, 
    2.1*a}}}; Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{Norm@#2/0.000001, Automatic, 
       h}}], Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ listb]`

Comment: Perfect! That solves my problem!! Update your answer, and I will mark it as solved. Thank you.

Comment: @Mencia out of curiosity did you try my solution as well?

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries @Mr.Wizard♦ how can I put edge to this figure? I tried with EdgeForm[Thick], but it did not work. Any help?

Comment: You mean a frame around the whole figure? Use `Framed` in that case. Or do you mean you want a thick edge around the arrow head? `EdgeForm` should work but you might want to remove the filling of the polygon to see it; use `FaceForm[]` for that.

Comment: @Mencia [Please read this.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56158/121)

Answer (score 2):

How about [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html)-ing the `Arrowheads` size to zero below a certain threshold?

```
{Arrowheads[Chop[Norm@#2/0.0001, 1/100]], Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ listb
```

Comment: By changing the size of the arrowheads: a = 10^-8; listb = {{{0, 0}, {2.1*a, -2.1*a}}, {{1, 0}, {2.1*a, 2.1*a}}}; Graphics[{Arrowheads[Norm@#2/0.000001], Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ listb] . Can you see how there is some dot/cross at the end of the arrowhead? That's the thing I want to get rid of .

Comment: @Mencia Yes, but using `Chop` with the appropriate threshold solves that problem.  Are you having trouble applying this?

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard♦ thank you very much. Your solution works as well as the other one. I happened to try the other one first.

Comment: @Mencia No problem; just curious.