# Export to PDF so that Adobe Illustrator does not convert PlotMarkers to fonts

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

I would like to export a *Mathematica* graph as PDF, then use Adobe Illustrator to manipulate it. So, I create the graph, and export it:

```
lSine = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
g1 = ListPlot[lSine, Joined -> True,  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 14}]
Export["plotMarkers.pdf", g1]
```

The graph looks like this in *Mathematica*:

[image]

However, when I open the PDF in illustrator, I get the following:

[image]

And the triangle markers have been replaced by a font called 'Myriad Pro', which looks terrible.

I would like to export the file in PDF format, but stop Illustrator from thinking that the markers are fonts. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have seen this question, which tackles the somewhat similar issue, but for an actual font. However, I can't see anything exactly analogous to this issue. Note: I *could* export the file as a JPG and avoid this issue, but I want to keep the PDF quality.

Comment: The default `PlotMarkers` *are* font glyphs.  See [(2216)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2216/121).  Try adding `"TextMode"->"Outlines"` to `Export` and see if that solves it.  Another, I would argue better, solution is to use non-glyph markers, e.g. [(84857)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84857/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for your message. Using "TextMode"->"Outlines" didn't work, but using non-glyph markers did. Thanks very much! Best, Ben

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default plot markers are glyphs from a *Mathematica* font:

```
Graphics`PlotMarkers[]
```

> ```
> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 8.96}, {"\[FilledSquare]", 8.96}, {"\[FilledDiamond]", 
>   10.88}, {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 10.24}, {"\[FilledDownTriangle]", 
>   10.24}, {"\[EmptyCircle]", 10.24}, {"\[EmptySquare]", 10.24}, {"\[EmptyDiamond]", 
>   10.24}, {"\[EmptyUpTriangle]", 11.136}, {"\[EmptyDownTriangle]", 11.136}}
> ```

Illustrator can't recognize this font and replaces it with a "similar" font during import. For producing publication-quality graphs it is highly recommended don't use glyph-based plot markers because *Mathematica* [can't position them exactly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/280). The best is to use primitive-based custom plot markers and there is a convenient package for this:

- [How can we make publication-quality PlotMarkers without version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84857/280)

Another possibility is to define primitive-based plot markers yourself, for example as shown in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56158/280) answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment under my answer., now I remember I saw those posts before. +1