# Plot marker edges appear gray in the legend instead of black, as they do in the plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to get my PlotMarkers to appear in the Legend as they do on the plot. I've set up a function named square[], that makes a square with black edges. When apply this function in 'LegendMarkers' the edges appear gray in the Legend.  Its really annoying? Any ideas on how to fix this? image and script are below.

[image]

```
square[in_, out_: Black, size_: 12] := 
 Graphics[{in, EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[1.5], out}], Rectangle[]}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> size]

data = {{2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}, {5, 25}, {6, 36}}

legend = PointLegend[{Style["test", 18]} , 
   LegendMarkers -> square[Red]];

ListPlot[data,
 PlotMarkers -> {square[Red]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, {.2, .7}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Grayish edges on the legend markers are the result of default setting for marker style:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle
```

> `EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.3], GrayLevel[0]]]`

You can reset the default edge opacity to `Opacity[1]`:

```
Legending`LegendDump`$DefaultMarkerStyle = EdgeForm[Opacity[1]];

PointLegend[{Red}, {Style["test", 18]}, LegendMarkers -> square[Red], 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 20]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Change the default value of the second argument to set the `Opacity` of edges to `1`:

```
square2[in_, out_: Opacity[1, Black], size_: 12] := 
 Graphics[{in, EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[1.5], out}], Rectangle[]}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> size]
```

Compare `sqare` vs. `square2`:

```
PointLegend[{Red}, {Style["test", 18]}, LegendMarkers -> square[Red], 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
PointLegend[{Red}, {Style["test", 18]}, LegendMarkers -> square2[Red],
  LegendMarkerSize -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> square2[Red], 
 PlotLegends ->  Placed[PointLegend[{Style["test", 18]}, 
    LegendMarkers -> square2[Red]], {.2, .7}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why is this tweak mecessary for the legend but not the plot?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting observation.  You appear to be using code from my answer to [Change the inner color of markers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56155/change-the-inner-color-of-markers/56158#56158) and on inspection I saw that the legends there were affected as well.  I have amended my code to specify a solid [`Opacity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html).

The question remains however why this happens.  Looking at the Box out gives us a clue:

```
PointLegend[{1}, {"test"}, LegendMarkers -> square[Red]] // ToBoxes
```

In that large output we have:

```
GraphicsBox[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[2], GrayLevel[0]}], 
  RectangleBox[{0, 0}]}, {DefaultBaseStyle -> {"Graphics", {AbsolutePointSize[6]}, 
    Directive[EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.3`], GrayLevel[0]]], PointSize[0.5`], 
     AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]]}, ImageSize -> 13}]
```

So somewhere a [`DefaultBaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultBaseStyle.html) that includes an [`EdgeForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeForm.html) with `` Opacity[0.3`] `` is inserted.

This seems to be a stylistic choice for e.g.

```
SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, Automatic] ~Magnify~ 3
```

[image]

I don't know if you are interested in tracking down the ultimate source of this directive or if that answers your question.  kglr gave the direct solution, and if you use `marker` from my referenced answer you will find it now works too.