# Custom PlotMarkers with Graphics get cut

Tags: plotting, graphics, marker

In attempt to accurately place points in a `ListPlot`, I'm using custom `PlotMarkers` made from `Graphics` as described by @Mr.Wizard [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56158/), but they're coming out truncated:

```
ListPlot[{1, 2}, PlotMarkers ->
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 8, AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0}]]
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to get the whole marker to show?

```
$Version
(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)
```

Comment: I see the same thing "13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `ImagePadding -> 1`:

```
ListPlot[{1, 2}, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 8, 
   AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0}, ImagePadding -> 1]]
```

> [image: out]

But I recommend using [`ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker) instead:

```
ListPlot[{1, 2}, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]["Circle", Offset[5], {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White]}]]
```

> [image: out2]