# How to make ListPlot points not pixelated while decreasing PointSize?

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I was using `ListPlot` and noticed `PlotStyle -> {Directive[Dotted, AbsolutePointSize[0.001]]}` makes the points pixelated (squared) instead of keeping the points rounded as original.

Without `PlotStyle`:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10000, 2}];
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

With `PlotStyle`:

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Dotted, PointSize[0.0001]]}, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "CoolColor"}]
```

[image]

I thought increasing the image resolution might solve the problem. However, it turned out to be futile even with `PlotMarkers`.

```
Block[{$ImageResolution = 500},
 Rasterize[
  ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> ".", 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Dotted, PointSize[0.0001]]}, 
   PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "PastelColor"}]]]
```

[image]

> **How do I make the points retain their round shape while decreasing size?**

As suggested by @[Domen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/75628/domen), I followed [the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272785/84456) to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/272775/84456) and tried this approach. However, even though it works, I cannot have `ImageSize` go for less than $4$, and I am stuck with a single colour.

```
ListPlot[data, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 4, 
   AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0}, ImagePadding -> 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you confuse the situation by adding a PlotTheme, but that notwithstanding, at some small enough size the points will be represented by a single pixel, and it will have whatever shape pixels have on your output device. I also have a hard time reproducing your "pixelated" result on my computer. The points just look too small to have a discernible shape, no matter how much I enlarge the plot.

Comment: Okay! So there is no way to have rounded points at this `PointSize` on my computer, right?

Comment: The issue is that the markers get clipped, that's why they look like squares. Does using a customized default marker with increased `PlotRangePadding` work? Namely: ```marker = Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsPlotMarkers[][[1, 1]] /. (PlotRangePadding -> _) -> (PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.4]); ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {marker, Scaled[0.03]}]```

Comment: See also [Custom PlotMarkers with Graphics get cut](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272775/custom-plotmarkers-with-graphics-get-cut).

Comment: Thank you @Domen for your responce. I tried `ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {marker, Scaled[0.01]}]` with the marker you defined and it doesn't work as expected. Please, see the updated question.

Comment: But you didn't try the code in my comment :) [It should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbcfC.png).

Comment: I did try your code based on your comment. It does work, but I can't scale it below $0.001$. The `Scaled[0.0001]` gives the same point size as `Scaled[0.001]`