# How to make PlotMarkers constructed from Graphics track plot style?

Tags: plotting, graphics, style

In this plot the `Disk[]` markers are not colored according to the style of the line to which they belong:

```
SeedRandom[12]
data = Accumulate /@ RandomReal[3, {4, 10}] {1, 2, 3, 4};

ListLinePlot[data,
  PlotMarkers -> Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 13],
  PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

Curiously, note that they are colored in the legend.  How can I make the lines match the legend?

Comment: I didn't expect to see a bounty on this.  Thank you, Szabolcs!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Though I was expecting to need something fancy I stumbled upon a simple solution:

```
ListLinePlot[data,
  PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 13],
  PlotLegends -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

The only change is enclosing `Disk[]` in `{ }`.

Looking at the InputForm we see that expressions involving `Disk` have been changed to e.g.:

```
Graphics[{
  Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Directive[PointSize[0.019444444444444445], 
  RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], 
  Disk[{0, 0}]
}, ImageSize -> 13]
```

Apparently when a `List` appears as the first argument of `Graphics` the plot routine prepends the style information.

As far as I know this behavior is undocumented.

Comment: You used a degenerate case (single element, i.e., cycle of one) of the documented: "With PlotMarkers -> {Subscript[g, 1],\[Ellipsis],Subscript[g, n]} the Subscript[g, i] are used cyclically for successive dataset lists." (from PlotMarkers documentation) However, using Automatic markers enables distinguishing the different lines even when seen in black and white.  `ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 16}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: @BobHanlon I don't know if I understand your point but if I do I do not agree with it.  I am using the form: "g markers consisting of copies of expression g"  There is nothing "degenerate" about it that I can see.

Comment: My interpretation is that the list you added inside of the `Graphics` constitutes the cycle list (length of one) used for the markers. But I could easily be wrong.

Comment: I almost sure this issue already was discussed on this site or on stackoverflow.com several years ago. So this is an old stumbling point. Thank you for bringing attention to this again. Now I understand why I always "unintentionally" wrap the first argument of `Graphics` by `List`... ;)

Comment: @BobHanlon The same behavior is observed in non-degenerated cases (in your sense): `ListLinePlot[data,PlotMarkers->{Graphics[Disk[],ImageSize->13],Graphics[Disk[],ImageSize->13]}]`. So your interpretation is wrong. Personally I think it is just an ordinary example of gedanken functionality in *Mathematica*: the developer simply forgot to handle the case when the first argument of `Graphics` is not wrapped by `List`.

Comment: @Alexey Please link the old post if you should find or recall it.

Comment: not duplicate but related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5400/why-doesnt-plotmarker-option-none-return-no-plotmarkers

Comment: @Mike The second half of that question really seems to be a duplicate.  I'm not sure how to handle this.  The prime focus of that question seems to be something else, but I also don't like to spread things across multiple questions.  The more simplistic interpretation of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56155/121) is also a duplicate of your question but I think it allows another interpretation that is different. (That to which my answer applies.)  Do you think I should close this question or post a similar answer in reply to yours?

Comment: I thought the two questions were sufficiently different. Just added the link in my comment as a reference for anyone having problems with plot markers. My 2 cents is that I'd keep this as a separate question

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[12];
data = Accumulate /@ RandomReal[3, {4, 10}] {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

It works in V 13.3:

```
ListLinePlot[data,
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 13],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

But in this case I would use

```
ListLinePlot[data,
 PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledCircle]", 16],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

A (complete?) list of available [PlotMarkers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html)

[Shapes, Icons, and Related Characters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ShapesIconsAndRelatedCharacters.html)