# PlotLegends for ListPlot with more than 15 curves?

Tags: bugs, legending, plotting

fixed in **10.1** (windows)

---

I'm running into trouble getting the right `PlotMarkers` in the legend of a `ListPlot` of many curves. Simple example:

```
ListPlot[Table[{j, i}, {i, Range[20]}, {j, Range[3]}], Joined -> True, 
    PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}, PlotLegends -> Range[20]]
```

produces:

[image: labeled plot]

The legend has the right colors for all curves, but after the fifteenth curve, the markers reset instead of continuing to cycle as they do in the actual plot. If I use `PlotLegends->Automatic` instead of `PlotLegends->Range[20]`, the legend simply stops with the fifteenth curve.

Any idea what might be going on here?

**EDIT**: Thanks everybody! There are several different good solutions below. A couple people suggested that this is a bug, so I've added that tag.

Comment: Related: [(56327)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56327/121), [(66055)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66055/121)

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  I included code for the first two examples which I had forgotten.  Also, consider using `ListLinePlot` instead of `ListPlot` and `Joined -> True` -- it doesn't help this particular problem but it is shorter and seems to be better supported, e.g. [(58808)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58808/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Good point about `ListLinePlot`. I'm in the habit of using `Joined->True` because it makes it easy to switch among `ListPlot`, `ListLogPlot`, `ListLogLinearPlot`, and `ListLogLogPlot`, but is there a better way to do this with just `ListLinePlot`? I guess `ScalingFunctions` is an (undocumented) option.

Comment: Good point yourself; I think `Joined -> True` is the simplest method for the log plot functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this can be considered a bug, but it is also related to the (IMHO) non-bug behavior of automatic styling described in [PlotLegends won't generate automatically more than 15 labels in v10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66055/121).  We see that if we use `PlotLegends -> Automatic` the number of legends is limited to the number of styles:

```
ListPlot[Table[{j, i}, {i, Range[20]}, {j, Range[3]}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97] ~Array~ 13, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

In the main plot, and in the legend up to the number colors in `PlotStyle`, the plot markers are cycled five solid and five outlined.  However in the legend this cycle resets after the number of styles is expended.  For example it starts again five solid from 14 if we force additional legend items:

```
ListPlot[Table[{j, i}, {i, Range[20]}, {j, Range[3]}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97] ~Array~ 13, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}, 
 PlotLegends -> Range[20]]
```

[image]

The fact that the markers in the plot and legend get "out of sync" appears to be a fault, but understanding it we can solve the problem by providing a sufficient number of styles:

```
enough = ColorData[#, "ColorList"] & /@ Join[97, 13];

ListPlot[Table[{j, i}, {i, Range[20]}, {j, Range[3]}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}, PlotLegends -> Range[20], PlotStyle -> enough]
```

[image]

Alternatively if you make sure that the number of styles is a multiple of ten it will align but there will undesirably be repeats in the legend.

Answer (score 5):

`PlotMarkers` are passed to the legends via the `LegendMarkers` option. Here it looks like only 15 markers are being passed in, e.g.

```
In[3]:= plot = ListPlot[Table[{j, i}, {i, Range[20]}, {j, Range[3]}], 
   Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}, 
   PlotLegends -> Range[20]];

In[4]:= Cases[plot, HoldPattern[LegendMarkers -> l_] :> l, -1]

Out[4]= {{{"\[FilledCircle]", Large}, {"\[FilledSquare]", Large}, 
 {"\[FilledDiamond]", Large}, {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", Large}, 
 {"\[FilledDownTriangle]", Large}, {"\[EmptyCircle]", Large}, 
 {"\[EmptySquare]", Large}, {"\[EmptyDiamond]", Large}, 
 {"\[EmptyUpTriangle]", Large}, {"\[EmptyDownTriangle]", Large}, 
 {"\[FilledCircle]", Large}, {"\[FilledSquare]", Large}, 
 {"\[FilledDiamond]", Large}, {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", Large}, 
 {"\[FilledDownTriangle]", Large}}}
```

So, while [Mr.Wizard's suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77002/52) is the reliably correct method, I would suggest something different. `LegendMarkers` is cyclic in application, so you could simply reduce the number of markers used to 10, e.g.

```
plot /. HoldPattern[LegendMarkers -> l_] :> (LegendMarkers -> l[[;; 10]])
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
markers = {#, Large} & /@ PadRight[#, 20, #] &@ Graphics`PlotMarkers[][[All, 1]];

ListPlot[Table[{j, i}, {i, Range[20]}, {j, Range[3]}], Joined -> True, 
    PlotMarkers -> markers, PlotLegends ->LineLegend[Range[20], LegendMarkers ->  markers]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine in MMA 9:

```
ListPlot[Table[{j, i}, {i, Range[20]}, {j, Range[3]}], Joined -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[20]]]
```

[image]

**It looks like a bug in MMA v10**

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in **10.1**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
ListPlot[Table[{j, i}, {i, Range[20]}, {j, Range[3]}], 
Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}, PlotLegends -> Range[20]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making a list of all the `PlotMarkers`:

```
 ListPlot[
     Table[{j, i}, {i, Range[20]}, {j, Range[3]}],
     Joined -> True,
     PlotStyle -> Table[Hue[i/20], {i, 20}],
     PlotMarkers -> (Text[Style[#, 16]] & /@ CharacterRange["a", "z"]),
     PlotLegends -> Range[20]
         ]
```

[image]

I suspect that the default list of `PlotMarkers` has only 15 entries (in v. 10.0.0).

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the OP's problem. The 20 plot markers on the plot itself are all distinguishable.