# LegendMarkerSize doesn't work here?

Tags: plotting, legending, size

I'm trying to change the marker size on the legend of a figure.

Simply:

```
x = {1, 5, 10};

y = {1, 7, 31};

xy = Transpose@{x , y};

ListLogLogPlot[xy, PlotLegends -> {"hey", LegendMarkerSize -> 0.6}]
```

And, no matter which LegendMarkerSize I choose, I always get the same marker size in the legend.

[image]

Any idea on how to really change the size of the marker inside the legend?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You have 2 undetermined parameters: niterations, data and numberplot. This way it is impossible to repeat your results. We can start thinking on your question as soon as we can repeat and then play with your code. A good idea would be to add the definition of the missing values to your code.

Comment: Well, in fact it as only an example. I edit my question to simpler case where the same happens

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax to specify options for the legend. See @AlexeiBoulbitch's answer for the proper way

Answer (score 1):

For the case in OP (where the `PlotMarkers` option does not appear in the main plot), `LegendMarkerSize` option works as expected if `PointLegend` is used with its first argument set to the `PlotStyle` of the main plot:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{xy ,{1, 2} # & /@ xy}, 
  PlotLegends -> PointLegend[97, {"hey", "hey 2"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 40]]
```

[image]

```
ListLogLogPlot[{xy , {1, 2} # & /@ xy}, 
  PlotStyle -> (ps = "Rainbow"),
  PlotLegends -> PointLegend[ps, {"hey", "hey 2"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 60]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Specifying [`Disk`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html) markers corrects this:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{xy, 2 xy}
 , PlotMarkers -> {Graphics@{Disk[]}, .05}
 , PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"hey", "there"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 70]
]
```

[image]

Note that `{Disk[]}` is needed rather than simply `Disk[]` because of [How to make PlotMarkers constructed from Graphics track plot style?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56327/121)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLogLogPlot[xy, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"hey"}, LegendMarkerSize -> sz]], {sz, 
  0.5, 50}]
```

Generally, it seems that some problem causes the log-log character of the plot. Try to increase the marker size well beyond 50.

Have fun!

Comment: The behavior of this is weird though, and I don't think it has to do with the log plot. Try it with simple `ListPlot`: MMA appears to *make space* for a larger legend marker, but then the marker itself is always drawn at the same size.

Comment: @MarcoB that's because the marker is a textual form with a font-size. So, there is an effective upper limit to the marker size.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `PointSize` and `LegendMarkerSize` appear to be necessary to overcome the problem mentioned by [@rcollyer in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176464/legendmarkersize-doesnt-work-here#comment463130_176480), i.e. the fact that, since the marker is a textual form with a font-size, there is an effective upper limit to the marker size.

Here is a helper function that takes a plot with a `PointLegend` and replaces the appropriate values within the plot with new user-defined ones to enlarge the legend markers:

```
ClearAll[enlargeLegendMarker]
enlargeLegendMarker[plotobject_, newsize_] :=
 ReplaceAll[
  plotobject,
  Legended[plot_,
   Placed[
    legend_,
    options__]
  ] :>
  Legended[plot,
   Placed[
    Append[legend /. PointSize[_] -> PointSize[newsize], LegendMarkerSize -> 350 newsize],
    options
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

The function takes a plot and a new fractional marker size as arguments. Note that an appropriate `LegendMarkerSize` must be calculated depending on the `PointSize` to have enough room for each marker at size. This was done by trial and error. A value of $350\times$ the new fractional size seems to work well.

Some definitions:

```
xy = {{1, 1}, {5, 7}, {10, 31}};
plot = ListLogLogPlot[{xy, 2 xy}, PlotLegends -> {"hey", "you"}];
```

And some usage examples:

```
{Style[#, 20], enlargeLegendMarker[plot, #]} & /@ {0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.3} // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to do it.

```
xy = {{1, 1}, {5, 7}, {10, 31}};
    imgSize = 10;
      legend = Grid[ Transpose@{Graphics[{ColorData[97, #], Disk[]}, 
            ImageSize -> imgSize] & /@ Range@2, {"hey", "you"}}];

    ListLogLogPlot[{xy, 2 xy}, PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Right]]
```

[image]

imgSize = 20;

[image]