# Styling individual bars in a BarChart with grouped data

Tags: plotting, charts

Consider the following:

```
fakedata = RandomReal[{4, 9}, {5, 10}];
BarChart[fakedata, BarSpacing -> {0, 0.4}, 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[], 
 ChartStyle -> {{Magenta, Blue, Red, Orange, Green}, Opacity[#] & /@ Range[0.1, 1, 0.1]}]
```

[image]

This is all well and good, but what I really want is the following, but grouped, so that the bars are opaque, the ticks come out how I want them, and the little space in between the groups (from the `BarSpacing` option) shows up:

```
BarChart[Flatten@fakedata, BarSpacing -> {0, 0.4}, 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[], 
 ChartStyle -> 
  Flatten@Outer[Blend[{{0, White}, {0.7, #1}, {1.1, Black}}, #2] &, {Magenta, 
     Blue, Red, Orange, Green}, Range[0.1, 1, 0.1]]]
```

[image]

Unfortunately if I create a "matrix" of colours as the value of the `ChartStyle` option, only the second list is picked up, and I get this:

```
BarChart[fakedata, BarSpacing -> {0, 0.4}, 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[], 
 ChartStyle -> Outer[Blend[{{0, White}, {0.7, #1}, {1.1, Black}}, #2] &, {Magenta, 
    Blue, Red, Orange, Green}, Range[0.1, 1, 0.1]]]
```

[image]

How can I style my bars individually like in the second example, when the data are grouped?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 fakedata = RandomReal[{4, 9}, {5, 10}];
 styles = Outer[Blend[{{0, White}, {0.7, #1}, {1.1, Black}}, #2] &, {Magenta, Blue,
 Red, Orange, Green}, Range[0.1, 1, 0.1]];
 BarChart[MapThread[Style, {fakedata, styles}, 2] (*thanks: Verbeia & Mr.Wizard *),
 BarSpacing -> {0, 0.4}, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, one replace `MapThread[...]` by :

```
 Partition[Inner[Style, Flatten@fakedata, Flatten@styles, List], 10] (* thanks: VLC *)
 (* or *)
 ArrayReshape[Inner[Style, Flatten@fakedata, Flatten@styles, List], {5, 10}] (* Version  9 *)
```

**Update: Using *ChartElementFunction***

```
 cedFX[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := {Dynamic@
   Blend[{{0, White}, {0.7, CurrentValue["Color"]}, {1.1, Black}}, 
   ((1/10) Mod[xmin - .4 Quotient[xmin, 10], 10])],
   Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]}; 
  BarChart[fakedata, BarSpacing -> {0, 0.4}, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[],
  ChartElementFunction -> cedFX,
  ChartStyle -> {{Magenta, Blue, Red, Orange, Green}, None}]
```

[image]

(Note: needs better tuning of the blending parameter as a function of `xmin`,`xmax` and the value of the `BarSpacing` option)

Comment: Equivalent way to get the colors: `MapThread[
 Style[#1, #2] &, {fakedata52, 
  Outer[Blend[{{0, White}, {0.7, #1}, {1.1, Black}}, #2] &, {Magenta, 
    Blue, Red, Orange, Green}, Range[0.1, 1, 0.1]]}, 2]`. It's worth pointing out that if you have a custom function that uses the data anywhere (e.g. calculated the `Max` and `Min` to work out ticks, you can't just pass the `Style`d data to the function. You'd need to create a `SpecialStyles` type option to that function, and combine the styles and data together in the charting function.

Comment: @Verbeia, I will update with the alternative method. Re the potential issue with custom `Ticks`, `Gridlines` ... functions and `Style`-wrapped data in the first argument of a `_Chart/_Plot` function, such custom functions seem to work fine with `BarChart` (and, possibly others, especially those that _officially_ accept wrappers on the data). For example, I tried `GridLines -> (Join @@ {Thread[{Range[#1, #2, 10], Thick}, List,  1], {{#2/2, Thick}, 8}} &)` and `FrameTicks -> (Range[#1/2, #2, (#2 - #1)/5] &)` and both work as expected.

Comment: @kguler - yes, but unfortunately things like `Min`, `Max` and `FindDivisions` don't handle style-wrapped data so *my* custom ticks functions don't currently work :)

Comment: Why do so many great answers get so few votes?  There are some really nice tricks used here.  Where did you learn `CurrentValue["Color"]`? +2 if I could.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you. Learned `CurrentValue["Color"]` from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5143/125) by Yu-sung Chang.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard initially, this didn't interest me, so I did not vote on it. Looking at it again, revealed a gem.