# Controlling Bar Color in BarChart precisely

Tags: plotting, color, charts

I'm trying to control the color of individual bars in a `BarChart`when I pass a 2 dimensional list of data to plot. What I want to accomplish is that for each pair of adjacent bars I want to use a `ColorScheme` overall, however, make the right bar to be slightly `Darker` (see the last image for an example). No color is repeated.

I've tried various combinations of `{..., {None}, etc...}`, however, I can't figure out how to do what I want without flattening the list.

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}], ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}], ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I thought these might work:

```
colorfunc = ColorData["Pastel"];
colors = colorfunc /@ Range[0, 1, 1/4];
BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}], 
 ChartStyle -> {{colors, Darker/@colors}, None}]
```

but it returns an error.

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}], ChartStyle -> {Riffle[colors, Darker[#, 0.1] & /@ colors]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As I said I can accomplish what I want by flattening the list but this breaks the nice bar spacing and a lot of the automated features of the plotting.

```
BarChart[Flatten@RandomReal[1, {5, 2}], ChartStyle -> Riffle[colors, Darker[#, 0.1] & /@ colors]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I control specific specific bars in a `BarChart` with multi-dimensional data?

Comment: Is `BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}], 
 ChartStyle -> {None, {Blue, Darker[Blue]}}]` what you want?

Comment: @Silvia, unfortunately no. I edited my question to be more clear but I want to follow the ColorSheme overall for the left bar and then the right bar of each pair will be simply slightly darker. No color repeats.

Comment: How about this: `BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}], 
 ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", {Opacity[.6], Opacity[1]}}]`?

Comment: related Q/A: [Styling individual bars in a BarChart with grouped data](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19470/125)

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate.  If you disagree please vote to reopen and @ping me with reasons why.

Answer (score 3):

From what the documentation says, `ChartStyle` accepts no functions but only styles, so if it's acceptable for you, `Opacity` might be a possible replacement:

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}], 
   ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", {Opacity[.234], Opacity[1]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And you can process to what you want from the above one:

```
% /. {Directive[pre___, RGBColor[rgb__], Opacity[op_], post___] :> 
   Directive[pre, If[op - .234 == 0, RGBColor[rgb], Darker[RGBColor[rgb]]], post]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I was writing a comment that the `Opacity` causes the `GridLines` to show through half the bars but with your post-processing strategy the problem is solved!

Comment: @s0rce Always have fun with post-processing :)

Comment: Clever approach. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks~

Comment: I believe your replacement rule may be simplified.  May I make the edit?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard of course! please! :D

Comment: I realize that what I was thinking would require either losing the simplicity of the first graphic (which without GridLines etc. works fine) or changing the second so that the left bar is `Lighter` rather than making the right bar `Darker`.  (It would look more like the first graphic then, but work with GridLines.)  I don't know if this it suitable.  At least you can use `If[op == .234, . . .` which is a minor simplification.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes indeed. It's only my personal preference to choose `... == 0` than `... == ...`. (the attendance of exact `0` makes me mentally feel *safe* :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard btw I think it deserves an answer for so much differences of your procedure than mine.

Comment: I decided to take this in a different direction.  (See my answer.)  I hope it does not detract from your answer; it is my intention to complement it, *not* replace it.

Comment: It's totally fine. I think we're hanging out on this site for not reputations but having fun with *Mathematica*! ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is a tangential answer.

Silvia's answer shows a nice and clever method but it is somewhat complicated by the replacement rule needed for post-processing.  This made me realize that a new kind of directive would be convenient here, one which could be used in-line.  For example: `{. . ., Red, . . ., mkDarker[], . . .}` would replace `mkDarker[]` with `Darker@Red`.  First an illustration of the directive in use, using Silvia's method (I'll use `Glow` instead of `Opacity` just because I can):

```
ch = BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}], ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", {Glow[], Glow[0]}}];
ch /. Glow[0] :> mkDarker[]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or darker by a different amount:

```
ch /. Glow[0] :> mkDarker[0.6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And here is the code for the directive and `mkLighter` too while we're at it:

```
mkDarker /: (h : List | Directive)[Longest[a___], 
  color : _RGBColor | _Hue | _CMYKColor | _GrayLevel, b___, 
  mkDarker[n : (_?NumericQ) : 1/3], c___] := h[a, color, b, Darker[color, n], c]

mkLighter /: (h : List | Directive)[Longest[a___], 
  color : _RGBColor | _Hue | _CMYKColor | _GrayLevel, b___, 
  mkLighter[n : (_?NumericQ) : 1/3], c___] := h[a, color, b, Lighter[color, n], c]
```

Comment: Great +1! This is what it should be! I thought about similar things but gave up mainly because `TagSetDelayed` didn't come to my mind.

Comment: Would it be possible to use `mkDarker` directly in `ChartStyle`? Or maybe it will require a hack of option-check process of `BarChart`?

Comment: @Silvia I think it would require some kind of modification to `BarChart` and I thought it was best to avoid that, given how simple the post-processing rule can be when using this.

Comment: I traced to a function ``Charting`generalDirective``, setting it to ``Charting`generalDirective[mkDarker[_?NumericQ]] := True``, than it's OK to use `BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}], 
 ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", {mkDarker[0], mkDarker[.4]}}]`. It looks pretty safe to me.

Comment: @Silvia That sounds very useful.  You dug that out yourself?

Comment: I `Trace`-ed the entire `BarChart[...]`, found something like ``Charting`padMarkerStyle[BarChart, {2, 2}, {{Red, Blue}, {Opacity[.5], mkDarker[]}}]``, then I traced it with `TraceInternal -> True`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same tricks in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19473/125) to a related Q/A:

```
 data = RandomReal[1, {5, 2}]; 
 styles = {#, Darker[#, .1]} & /@ colors;
 BarChart[MapThread[Style[#1, #2] &, {data, styles}, 2], BarSpacing -> {0, 0.4}]
```

or

```
 BarChart[ Partition[Inner[Style, Flatten@data, Flatten@styles, List], 2], 
 BarSpacing -> {0, 0.4}]
```

or, for Version 9,

```
  BarChart[ ArrayReshape[Inner[Style, Flatten@data, Flatten@styles, List], {5, 2}],
  BarSpacing -> {0, 0.4}]
```

[image]

Comment: I missed that earlier question.  To me this one appears to be a duplicate.  Do you disagree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I agree; this is a simpler version of the linked question.