# "Stacked" BarChart with BarOrigin $\to$ Top makes y-tick marks negative

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

When `BarChart` layout is `"Stacked"`, setting `BarOrigin -> Top` makes the y-axis tick marks negative. [BarChart documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarChart.html) shows an example - but not "Stacked" - with correct positive y-axis tick marks.

For example,

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 10}], {3}, {4}];

BarChart[MapThread[Labeled[#1, #2, Above] &, {data, {1, 2, 3}}], 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 BarOrigin -> Top, 
 ChartStyle -> 
  Reverse@{Lighter@Blue, Blue, Darker@Blue, Darker@Darker@Blue}, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"a", "b", "c"}, None}, 
 Frame -> {False, True, False, False}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis"},
 FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14}]
```

Gives:

[image]

Is there an option to control this behavior without explicitly setting `FrameTicks -> {None, Table[{-i, i}, {i, 0, 25, 5}]}`, which works but is a hack.

Comment: The ticks are positive if without the `Frame -> {False, True, False, False}` option. I guess this setting overrides the internal procedure of `BarChart`?

Comment: I would say this is a bug and should probably be reported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By looking at the `InputForm` of the graphics in original post, I found a function `` Charting`FindTicks ``. It looks like what's needed.

Change `FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic}` to `` FrameTicks -> {None, Charting`FindTicks[{-1, 0}, {1, 0}]} ``:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Where did the x-axis frame label go? I can't seem to find it even if I adjust the `PlotRangePadding`

Comment: @s0rce Because OP sets `Frame -> {False, True, False, 
  False}`. Try `Frame -> {False, True, True, 
  False}, FrameLabel -> {{"y axis", None}, {None, "x axis"}}` etc.

Comment: +1 looks like you can also rescale ticks that way `Charting`FindTicks[{1, 0}, {0.5, 0}]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch It seems charts functions use a lot of special methods internally. Have seen many of them when [tracing `BarChart`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20079/controlling-bar-color-in-barchart-precisely/20080#comment61665_20084).

Comment: Yes I've used `Trace` on `Barchart`s before but the output was so large I didn't bother trying to figure it out!

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I'm trying to format the result from `Trace` to more human-readable forms. But maybe there are already some tools? Don't know..

Answer (score 5):

One possible, although probably not ideal solution is to remove the `Frame`. Since you are not using most of the `Frame` anyways this mostly changes where the `Labels` are put.

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 10}], {3}, {4}];

BarChart[MapThread[Labeled[#1, #2, Above] &, {data, {1, 2, 3}}], 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Top, 
 ChartStyle -> 
  Reverse@{Lighter@Blue, Blue, Darker@Blue, Darker@Darker@Blue}, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"a", "b", "c"}, None}, Frame -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis"}, FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic]

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a bug in `BarChart` in that the non-negative ticks are not applied to the Frame.
One can fix this by applying the frame afterward and porting the `Ticks` spec:

```
BarChart[MapThread[Labeled[#1, #2, Above] &, {data, {1, 2, 3}}], BarOrigin -> Top, 
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
  ChartStyle -> Reverse@{Lighter@Blue, Blue, Darker@Blue, Darker@Darker@Blue}, 
  ChartLabels -> {{"a", "b", "c"}, None}, FrameLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis"}];

Show[%, Frame -> {0, 1, 0, 0}, FrameTicks -> Options[%, Ticks][[1, 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Examination of the content of that option reveals the `` Charting`FindTicks `` function that Silvia posted, which is a more direct way in this case.  This answer however may illustrate a way of approaching other such problems which appear from time to time.