# How to retrieve current FaceForm?

Tags: graphics, dynamic, undocumented, style

The current colour in a Graphics object [can be retrieved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5138/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-lexically-current-colour-inside-graphics/5143#5143) using `CurrentValue["Color"]` for use in `Dynamic` stuff.

Example:

```
Graphics[
 {RGBColor[2/3, 1/3, 2/3],
  Dynamic[{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
     Darker@CurrentValue["Color"]], Disk[]}]
  }]
```

How can I retrieve the current `FaceForm` colour?

```
Graphics[
 {FaceForm[RGBColor[2/3, 1/3, 2/3]], EdgeForm[Black],
  Dynamic[{
     If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
        Darker@CurrentValue[(* what do I write here? *)]], 
     Disk[]}]
  }]
```

Comment: @Kuba [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19473/121) is a nice use of `CurrentValue["Color"]` if you have not seen it before.

Comment: @Kuba It's not at all academic.  I have a plotting function that plots some sort of "map", with the colours for each map area coming from the user.  At some point I found a need to highlight each area on hover, preferably while still keeping the shade of its colour.  Having access to the current colour value simplifies the code a lot because I don't need to re-build the whole map from the source data to add highlighting, I can just modify it.  In other words, it's not necessary to store the colours separately, they can just be a natural part of the Graphics object.

Comment: @Kuba What did you mean then?

Comment: @Kuba [Like this :-)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cazag1sxpv8bzcf/Screenshot%202015-06-27%2017.25.12.png?dl=0).  I was using tooltips to identify which area was which, but it turns out that sometimes the pointer location is inaccurate.  So I needed confirmation to know that I was indeed hovering the area I thought I was hovering.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Maybe I was too picky but OP example just asks about this approach. Moreover, I'm a little bit of pejudiced about styles/events inheritance as I faced couple of "exceptions" with events handlers. That's why I'm usually starting with brute force approach in such cases :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you want `"FrontFaceColor"` which can be found as a specification in [this list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71390/121):

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[RGBColor[2/3, 1/3, 2/3]], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Dynamic[{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Darker @ CurrentValue["FrontFaceColor"]], 
    Disk[]}]}]
```

[image][image]

You may also find `"FrontFaceOpacity"` of use.

---

Simply guessing I found that `"BackFaceColor"` is also valid, e.g.:

```
Graphics3D[
 {FaceForm[Yellow, Blue],
  Dynamic[{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], CurrentValue["BackFaceColor"]], Cuboid[]}]
 },
 PlotRange -> {{-1/4, 5/4}, {1/4, 5/4}, {-1/4, 5/4}}
]
```

[image][image]

Comment: And there's also `EdgeColor`.  Excellent!  Thank you, this'll simplify my code significantly.

Comment: @Szabolcs You're welcome.  I would appreciate your vote on [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71390/121) if I do not have it already; there's lots of great stuff in there just waiting to be applied!