# Creating new graphics primitive (EdgeForm, FaceForm)

Tags: graphics

My question is strongly related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5138/187), nevertheless I would like to bring it to everyone's attention. Let's say I want to create a new graphics primitive `Boing` which should look like this

```
Boing[] := 
 Polygon[Join[#1, Reverse[#2]] & @@@ 
   Partition[
    Table[{2 x/Pi, y/2*Cos[x]}, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2, 
      Pi/10}, {y, {-1, 1}}], 2, 1]]

Graphics[{Opacity[0.3, Blue], Boing[]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

As a new primitive, it should clearly work like other primitives like `Disk`, `Rectangle`, etc. When I define a `FaceForm` and `EdgeForm` one sees that this does not work because the settings are applied to the underlying `Polygons`

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Opacity[0.3, Blue]], 
  Boing[]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

In this case one could slightly re-arrange the points and create one overall polygon to circumvent the issue

```
Boing[] := 
 Polygon[Join[#1, Reverse[#2]] & @@ 
   Transpose[
    Table[{2 x/Pi, y/2*Cos[x]}, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2, 
      Pi/10}, {y, {-1, 1}}]]]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Opacity[0.3, Blue]], Boing[]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Unless I am mistaken, this is in general not possible without having access to the current values of `FaceForm` and `EdgeForm`. Consider the following example where I don't see a direct way

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Question:

What is the simplest solution to create a new graphics primitive which works like e.g. a polygon? To clarify: I want to be able to manually construct a new primitive and define how the settings of the current graphics state like  `FaceForm` or `EdgeForm` (`Texture`, `Specularity` or `Lighting` are further examples which change the state of the graphics engine) are handled.

## Update:

The answer of rm-rf was promising but unfortunately, `` Graphics`Mesh`PolygonCombine `` seems to have the same issues as I encountered above. This means, that for my target application it will not work. Consider the following example

```
points[r1_, r2_, n_] :=
  With[{dphi = 2.0 Pi/(n - 1)},
   Table[r {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, dphi}, {r, {r1, r2}}]
   ];

Graphics@{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], FaceForm[Opacity[0.3, Red]],
  Polygon[
   Function[{p1, p2}, Join[p1, Reverse[p2]]] @@@ 
    Partition[points[0.3, 0.7, 30], 2, 1]]}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And with `` Graphics`Mesh`PolygonCombine `` we get

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you will need to use `FilledCurve` to create objects with holes in.

For example:

```
points[r1_, r2_, n_] := With[{dphi = 2.0 Pi/(n - 1)}, 
   Table[r {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, dphi}, {r, {r1, r2}}]];

poly = Polygon[Function[{p1, p2}, Join[p1, Reverse[p2]]] @@@ 
    Partition[points[0.3, 0.7, 30], 2, 1]];

prim = FilledCurve[Thread[Graphics`Mesh`PolygonCombine @ poly] /. 
    Polygon[data_] :> {Line[data]}];
```

To make something that behaves more like a graphics primitive I will use my answer from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27209/862)

```
SetAttributes[createPrimitive, HoldAll];
createPrimitive[patt_, expr_] := 
 Typeset`MakeBoxes[p : patt, fmt_, Graphics] := 
  Typeset`MakeBoxes[Interpretation[expr, p], fmt, Graphics]

createPrimitive[donut, Evaluate@prim]
```

Now you can use `donut` in `Graphics`:

```
Graphics@{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], FaceForm[Opacity[0.3, Red]], donut}
```

[image]

Because `donut` has no downvalues, it remains unevaluated in the graphics expression:

```
InputForm[%]
(* Graphics[{EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0], Thickness[Large]}], 
    FaceForm[Opacity[0.3, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], donut}] *)
```

Comment: I haven't considered `FilledCurve` because I was disappointed that there seems to be no way to access the current state of a `Graphics` in between the drawing steps. I was particularly interested in this because in OpenGL this is possible for textures, colors, etc. I know hacks around this, but I was really curious that no one seems to miss this. Your answer is nevertheless the most direct way in this case. +1

Comment: @halirutan Not being able to access it might turn out to be a more serious problem when trying to write an exporter to another format which doesn't directly map to Mma's graphics representation.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the undocumented `PolygonCombine` to create a single polygon which behaves well with `EdgeForm` and `FaceForm`:

```
Boing2[] := Graphics`Mesh`PolygonCombine@Boing[]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Opacity[0.3, Blue]], Boing2[]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

In *Mathematica* 10/Wolfram Language/*Mathematica*-RPi, the function can be found under `` Graphics`PolygonUtils` ``. There might be some issues with self-intersecting polygons (I haven't looked into it), but this is a good start.

Comment: It is indeed a good start. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, for things with holes it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

In Mathematica 12 [`BoundaryMeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryMeshRegion) objects can be used as a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) primitive. So, another idea is to use a [`BoundaryMeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryMeshRegion) as your primitive. For example:

```
Typeset`MakeBoxes[
    CutoutEllipse[center_, out_, in_],
    form_,
    Graphics
] := With[
    {
    new = Replace[
        RegionDifference[Disk[center, out], Disk[center, in]],
        b_BooleanRegion :> BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[b]
    ]
    },
    Typeset`MakeBoxes[new, form, Graphics]
]
```

Examples:

```
Graphics[{Pink, EdgeForm[Blue], CutoutEllipse[{0,0}, {4,2}, .9 {1,2}]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{Pink, EdgeForm[Blue], CutoutEllipse[{0,0}, {4,2}, 1.1 {1,2}]}]
```

[image]

You can use this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198915/45431) to get the above approach to work in earlier versions of Mathematica.

Comment: In V12 we can also have explicitly have polygons with holes.

Answer (score 4):

`FilledCurve` seems to do exactly what you want

Comment: Do you mind including in your answer how to plot the examples given in the question by using `FilledCurve`?

Comment: Sorry , didn't included it because the example in the first page of the reference documentation is really close to the requirement. Just needs a few adjustments for the shape.

Comment: Don't bother now. @SimonWoods  did it.

Answer (score 2):

Posting a separate answer, as this is really a completely different approach. While it seems impossible to access the current setting for `FaceForm` and `EdgeForm` in between the drawing steps, it *is* possible to temporarily change them for a particular primitive with `Style`.

So you can show the original polygon with no edges, and the combined polygon with no faces:

```
points[r1_, r2_, n_] := With[{dphi = 2.0 Pi/(n - 1)}, 
   Table[r {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, dphi}, {r, {r1, r2}}]];

poly = Polygon[Function[{p1, p2}, Join[p1, Reverse[p2]]] @@@ 
    Partition[points[0.3, 0.7, 30], 2, 1]];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], FaceForm[Opacity[0.3, Red]], 
  Style[poly, EdgeForm[]], 
  Style[Graphics`Mesh`PolygonCombine[poly], FaceForm[]]
  }]
```

[image]