# Undesirable grid appears when ParametricPlot is exported as PDF

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

Writing:

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{x, Min[1, 2] t}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
                       PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 2}}]
```

I get:

[image]

but if I write:

```
Export["test.pdf", plot]
```

I get:

[image]

How can I get the same image in `test.pdf`?

Comment: How about this? `plot = Plot[1, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 2}}, 
  Frame -> True, Filling -> Axis, AspectRatio -> 1.5,PlotStyle -> Thin]`

Comment: You can try Will Robertson's [`FixPolygons`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7029/) package for joining the polygons.

Comment: Does this help? [Avoiding white lines inside filled area in RegionPlot exported as PDF or PS](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2638/245)

Comment: What's up with `Min[1, 2] t`? Surely that can be replaced by `t` alone? Or doesn't the problem reproduce then?

Comment: TeM, could you check if `SetSystemOptions["VisualizationOptions" -> {"GraphicsComplexPolygonCombine" -> True}];plot = ParametricPlot[{x, Min[1, 2] t}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 2}}];Export["test.pdf", plot]` works in your version/OS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: See more general solution in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179990/280) answer.

---

You can solve this problem by joining the polygons using undocumented function [`` Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38754/280):

```
plot = Normal@
   ParametricPlot[{x, Min[1, 2] t}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 2}}] /. 
  p : {__Polygon} :> Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[p];

Export["test.pdf", plot] // SystemOpen
```

Here is how the file is rendered by Adobe Acrobat:

[image: screenshot]

(checked with version 11.1.0).

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to remove transparency from the polygons by specifying the `PlotStyle` explicitly:

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{x, Min[1, 2] t}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 2}}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> RGBColor[{0.812, 0.851, 0.914, 1}]]
```

> [image: output]

Now the PDF

```
Export["test.pdf", %] // SystemOpen
```

is rendered as

[image: screenshot]