# Problem with Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine

Tags: plotting, undocumented, polygons

Writing:

```
Normal@ParametricPlot[{x, x^2 t}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}] /. 
p : {__Polygon} :> Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[p]
```

I get:

[image]

but if I write:

```
Normal@ParametricPlot[{x, x^2 t}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, .1}] /. 
p : {__Polygon} :> Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[p]
```

I get:

[image]

How can I avoid this problem by having to use this function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A small modification of the original code solves the problem:

```
Normal@ParametricPlot[{x, x^2 t}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, .1}] /. 
 p : {{__Polygon} ..} :> Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[p]
```

> [image: output]

The new code also works for the [initial problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/179951/280).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine `` on *all* polygons rather than on groups of polygons separately:

```
pp = ParametricPlot[{x, x^2 t}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, .1}] ;
allpolygons = Join @@ Cases[Normal@pp, {__Polygon}, Infinity];
Graphics[{ EdgeForm[Darker@LightBlue], Opacity[.5, LightBlue],  
  Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[allpolygons]}, Options[pp]]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Or simpler: ``Normal@ParametricPlot[{x, x^2 t}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, .1}] /. 
 p : {{__Polygon} ..} :> Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[p]``.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, i could have sworn that I tried that first; somehow it didn't work then:)  You might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @TeM, some are collected in  [What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/125)