# Others problems with Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine

Tags: plotting, graphics, calculus-and-analysis, undocumented, polygons

As a continuation of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179987/problem-with-graphicspolygonutilspolygoncombine), writing:

```
a = {x, 0};

b = 1.54;

f[x_] = Piecewise[{{a, x >= 1.38}, 
                   {{x, 0.27 (y - 1) (x - 1.38)}, 1.27 <= x < 1.38}, 
                   {{x, 0.48 (y - 1) (x - 1.33)}, True}}];

Normal@ParametricPlot[f[x], {x, 0, b}, {y, 0, 1}, 
                      MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #4 &}, Mesh -> {{0}, {1}},
                      MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.005], Green],
                      Directive[Thickness[0.005], Black]}, 
                      Exclusions -> None, 
                      PlotRange -> All, 
                      PlotStyle -> Green
                     ] /. p : {{__Polygon} ..} :> Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[p]
```

I get a correct output:

[image]

and the same, for example, for `a = {x (1 - y) + x y, 0}` and `b = 2.30`.

On the other hand, if I use `a = {x, 0}` and `b = 1.53` or `a = {x (1 - y) + x y, 0}` and `b = 2.40` I get:

[image]

which is clearly problematic. How do I combine the polygons in this case?

---

In response to *Carl Woll*:

```
g[x_] = Piecewise[{{{x, -0.12 x (x - 3.99) (y - 1)}, 2.61 <= x <= 3.00}, 
                   {{x, -0.24 x (x - 3.30) (y - 1)}, True}}];

Normal@ParametricPlot[g[x], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 1}, 
                      MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #4 &}, Mesh -> {{0}, {1}},
                      MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.005], Green],
                      Directive[Thickness[0.005], Black]}, 
                      Exclusions -> None, 
                      PlotRange -> All, 
                      PlotStyle -> Green
                     ] /. p : {__Polygon} :> Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[p]
```

[image]

Comment: In your other example, use ``p:{__Polygon} :> Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine[p]``

Comment: Side info: If you want to use inline code that contains backticks, simply use **two** backticks at the beginning and the end. If your code ends in a backtick, don't forget to put a whitespace between this trailing backtick and the two closing backticks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion) instead of [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot). For instance:

```
reg = ParametricRegion[
    {
    x,
    Piecewise[
        {
        {-.12x(x-3.99)(y-1),2.61<=x<=3.00}
        },
        -.24x(x-3.30)(y-1)
    ]
    },
    {{x,0,3},{y,0,1}}
];

mesh = DiscretizeRegion[reg]
```

[image]

You can use a different undocumented internal function to combine the simplices in the [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion):

```
simple = Region`Mesh`Simplify2DMesh @ mesh
```

[image]

You can use [`MeshPrimitives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshPrimitives) to extract the [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon):

```
polygon = MeshPrimitives[simple, 2]
```

> {Polygon[{{1.4985, 0.}, {1.42298, 0.}, {1.34747, 0.}, {1.27195, 
>       1.37468*10^-16}, {1.19643, 1.34121*10^-16}, {1.12092, 0.}, {1.0454, 
>       0.}, {0.969883, 
>       0.}, {0.894367, -5.7328*10^-17}, {0.822559, -5.4299*10^-17}, {0.750751, 
>       0.}, {0.678943, 0.}, {0.607134, 8.71267*10^-17}, {0.531618, 
>       0.}, {0.456102, 0.}, {0.380585, 0.}, {0.305069, 0.}, {0.229552, 
>       0.}, {0.154036, 0.}, {0.0785194, 0.}, {0.0407612, 0.}, {0.0218821, 
>       2.63813*10^-19}, {0.0124426, 3.95719*10^-19}, {0.00772278, 
>       4.61672*10^-19}, {0.003003, 5.27626*10^-19}, {0., 
>       0.}, {0.003003, -0.00237621}, {0.0127835, -0.0100164}, {0.022564, -0.0176567}, {0.042125, -0.0329371}, {0.081247, -0.0627634}, {0.159491, -0.120212}, {0.237735, -0.174722}, {0.315979, -0.226293}, {0.394223, -0.274926}, {0.472467, -0.32062}, {0.550711, -0.363375}, {0.628955, -0.403192}, {0.705656, -0.439372}, {0.782358, -0.472727}, {0.859059, -0.503259}, {0.93576, -0.530967}, {1.00938, -0.554904}, {1.08299, -0.57624}, {1.15661, -0.594975}, {1.23022, -0.611109}, {1.29767, -0.623607}, {1.36511, -0.633921}, {1.43256, -0.642052}, {1.5, -0.648}, {1.56744, -0.651764}, {1.63489, -0.653345}, {1.70233, -0.652743}, {1.76978, -0.649957}, {1.84339, -0.644424}, {1.91701, -0.63629}, {1.99062, -0.625554}, {2.06424, -0.612217}, {2.14094, -0.595554}, {2.21764, -0.576068}, {2.29434, -0.553757}, {2.37104, -0.528623}, {2.44929, -0.500073}, {2.52753, -0.468585}, {2.60578, -0.434158}, {2.68402, -0.420633}, {2.76226, -0.40696}, {2.84051, -0.391817}, {2.91875, -0.375205}, {2.95787, -0.366348}, {2.97744, -0.361735}, {2.997, -0.357123}, {3., -0.356043}, {3., -0.351396}, {3., -0.346748}, {3., -0.337452}, {3., -0.318862}, {3., -0.300271}, {3., -0.28168}, {3., -0.245232}, {3., -0.227741}, {3., -0.21025}, {3., -0.1782}, {3., -0.162175}, {3., -0.14615},
>   {3., -0.128659}, {3., -0.111168}, {3., -0.0929441}, {3., -0.0747199}, {3., -0.0561291}, {3., -0.0375383}, {3., -0.0189475}, {3., -0.00965215}, {3., -0.00500445}, {3., -0.000356757}, {2.997, 0.}, {2.97807, 0.}, {2.95914, 
>       0.}, {2.92129, 0.}, {2.84559, 0.}, {2.76988, 
>       0.}, {2.69418, -4.65117*10^-17}, {2.61848, -4.78458*10^-17}, {2.54277, -5.13045*10^-17}, {2.46707, -1.09507*10^-16}, {2.39136, -1.15794*10^-16}, {2.31956, -6.05967*10^-17}, {2.24775, 0.}, {2.17594, 0.}, {2.10413, 
>       1.34094*10^-16}, {2.02843, 1.37452*10^-16}, {1.95272, 
>       1.402*10^-16}, {1.87702, 1.42337*10^-16}, {1.80131, 
>       1.43864*10^-16}, {1.72561, 1.44779*10^-16}, {1.64991, 
>       1.45084*10^-16}, {1.5742, 1.44778*10^-16}}]}

*(it is possible to simplify this [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon) further if desired, as there are many collinear line segments)*

You can include the above polygon in your [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot) with [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog):

```
ParametricPlot[
    g[x],
    {x,0,3},
    {y,0,1},
    MeshFunctions->{#4&,#4&},
    Mesh->{{0},{1}},
    MeshStyle -> {
        Directive[Thickness[0.005], Green],
        Directive[Thickness[0.005], Black]
    },
    Exclusions->None,
    PlotRange->All,
    Epilog -> {LightGreen, polygon}
]
```

[image]