# Colour of contour labels

Tags: plotting, graphics, customization

My show is an overlay of 3 sets of countours in 3 different colours, but the countour labels are all black which makes identification problematic. I don't seem to be able to find a way to make the countour labels the same colour as their contours.

Comment: You need to post in a code block the executable code that demonstrates the problem you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 6):

```
ContourPlot[
 Sin[x] Sin[y],
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 ContourStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Green},
 ContourLabels ->
  (Text[Style[#3,
      Switch[#3,
       -0.8 | -0.2 | 0.4, Red,
       -0.6 | 0 | 0.6, Black,
       -0.4 | 0.2 | 0.8, Green]],
     {#1, #2}] &),
 BaseStyle -> 18]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** If the pure [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) using [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) designations is difficult to read, you can write this as

```
ContourPlot[
 Sin[x] Sin[y],
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Green}, 
 ContourLabels ->
  Function[{x, y, contourValue},
   Text[Style[contourValue,
     Switch[contourValue,
      -0.8 | -0.2 | 0.4, Red,
      -0.6 | 0 | 0.6, Black,
      -0.4 | 0.2 | 0.8, Green]],
    {x, y}]],
 BaseStyle -> 18]
```

**EDIT 2:** The default number of contour lines is nine. The contour lines will occur at function values of

```
lines = Module [{fmin = -1., fmax = 1., fdel},
  fdel = (fmax - fmin)/10;
  Range[fmin + fdel, fmax - fdel, fdel] // Chop]

(*  {-0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}  *)
```

For a cycle of three colors, the groupings will be

```
With[{numberOfColors = 3},
 Partition[lines, numberOfColors] // Transpose]

(*  {{-0.8, -0.2, 0.4}, {-0.6, 0, 0.6}, {-0.4, 0.2, 0.8}}  *)
```

This will obviously change for different function ranges, number of contours, and number of colors.

Comment: Nice, and one could change that `Switch` to take the `ColorData` of the underlying contour plot too. Might need a `Lighter@*` on it too so it doesn't wholly blend in I guess.

Comment: Great. That code worked pasted in and does more than I need. Sorry I don't understand it enough to modify it to just do the contours all in Red and the contour labels in Red too as I want with my function.It is the # stuff I don't get, Simon

Comment: @simon - look at the documentation for `Function` and `Slot`. Links include in edit above.

Comment: I entertained this approach but I do not see how to find the values `-0.8 | -0.2 | 0.4` etc. robustly, without turning to post-processing again.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - this approach is not particularly robust but tailoring is straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to use post-processing is to take advantage of the `Tooltip`s that are automatically generated by `ContourPlot` when the option `ContourLabels` is not used:

```
addColoredLabels = # /. 
    Tooltip[{x___, l : Line[__] ..}, z_] :> {x, l, 
      Dynamic@Text[Style[z, Darker@Darker@CurrentValue["Color"]], RandomChoice[#[[1]]],
           Background -> Opacity[.5, Lighter@Lighter@CurrentValue["Color"]]] & /@ {l}} &;
```

Example:

```
addColoredLabels @ ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ContourStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"], 
   BaseStyle -> {Thick, 18, Bold}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A simpler version of that function without the arcane `CurrentValue["Color"]`*.

```
colorSimple = # /. 
    Tooltip[{x___, l__Line}, z_] :> {x, l, 
       Text[Style[z, Opacity[1]], RandomChoice @@ #] & /@ {l}} &;
```

[image]

* [Is there a way to access the (lexically) current colour inside Graphics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5138/121)

Comment: Nice solution!  Surely safer than mine.  But I think you obfuscate it too much.  I am going to add a simpler version for those who have trouble following the first code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, much nicer, thank you. Makes me think "what was i thinking?"

Answer (score 4):

There does not appear to be any way to do this natively.  Here is an attempt at a post-processing work-around:

```
syncCountourLabels[g : Graphics[_GraphicsComplex, ___]] :=
  Module[{text, i = 1, pos = FirstPosition[g, {__Text}]},
   (
    text = Reverse @ Extract[g, pos];
    Delete[g, pos] /. x_Line :> {x, {Opacity[1], text[[i++]]}}
    ) /; pos =!= Missing["NotFound"]
  ]
```

Example:

```
ContourPlot[
  Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Green},
  ContourLabels -> True, 
  BaseStyle -> 18
] // syncCountourLabels
```

[image]